# JDBC Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I've got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Subject
```

with this WHERE clause :

```
WHERE Tag like '%something%'
```

This query works fine with SQL Manager, but JDBC keeps crashing with this exception:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

The code is:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Subject";
if (tags != null && tags.length>0) {
    for(int i = 0;i<tags.length;i++){
       query = query + " WHERE Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'";
    }
}
```

and so on.

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Could you post the exception too?

Comment: and some values for `tags`

Comment: If you have multiple tags, you're getting multiple `WHERE` statements. Not good ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over the "WHERE". Adding it with each new tag.

```
    String[] tags = new String[2];
    tags[0] = "bob";
    tags[1] = "hank";

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Subject";

    if (tags != null && tags.length>0) {
        for(int i = 0;i<tags.length;i++){
            query = query + " WHERE Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(query);
```

This will return

```
SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE Tag like '%bob%' WHERE Tag like '%hank%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course it will crash because the final query is not correct, consider you have this piece of information :

```
String tags[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
String query = "SELECT * FROM Subject";

for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    query = query + " WHERE Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'";
}
System.out.println(query);
```

This should return :

```
SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE Tag like '%aa%' WHERE Tag like '%bb%' WHERE Tag like '%cc%'
//---------------------^^--------------------^^--------------------^^
```

And this not correct Syntax.

---

To avoid this problem you have to use :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE ";
String or = "";
for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    query += or +" Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'";
    or = " OR ";
}
```

This can show you :

```
SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE  Tag like '%aa%' OR  Tag like '%bb%' OR  Tag like '%cc%'
```

---

**Note**

This still not perfect, to avoid any syntax error or SQL Injection i suggest to use PreparedStatement, for example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    //query += or + " Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'";
    query += or + " Tag like ?";
    or = " OR ";
}
//query = SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE  Tag like ? OR  Tag like ? OR  Tag like ?
Connection connection = null;
try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= tags.length; i++) {
        stm.setString(i, "%" + tags[i-1] + "%");//set values to your query
    }
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();//execute your query
    while(rs.next()){
        //get your results
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about using `Stream.of(tags).map(t->" Tag like ?").collect(joining(" OR "))` to build the where clause. It is much easier to read than the classic for loop.

Comment: yes, this is totally correct and good way, thank you @MalteHartwig appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Subject";

    if (tags != null && tags.length > 0) {
        query += " WHERE "; // do this once

        for(int i = 0;i < tags.length; i++){
            query += " Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'";
            query += " OR ";
        }

        query = query.substring(0, query.lenght() - 3); // Remove last "OR"
    }
```

Comment: Think about using `Stream.of(tags).map(t->" Tag like '%" + tags[i] + "%'").collect(joining(" OR "))` to build the where clause. It is much easier to read than the classic for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem.
I didn't reset the query at the start of each loop's round.
In fact it added a WHERE clause each time.
Now it works fine.